# Object received a naive datetime (...) while time zone support is active

Tags: python, django, datetime

I've been looking for an answer for this with no luck.
I'm creating and object that has an attribute called "accessdate"

When I create the object I receive the next warning

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Consumption.addedtime received a naive datetime (2020-06-01 13:07:47.222534) 
while time zone support is active
```

The thing is that what the object is reciving is NOT a naive datetime because it has the tzinfo filled with "Europe/Madrid" timezone.

These are the relevant imports I'm using:

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware
```

This is how I create my datetime variable:

```
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(data_from_request['FECHA ACTIVACION'], '%d/%m/%Y')
# data_from_request['FECHA ACTIVACION'] = '01/01/2020'
access_date = make_aware(date_object)
```

This is the model:

```
class Consumption(models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo de Consumos"""
    ...
    accessdate = models.DateField("Fecha de acceso", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    ...
```

And this is how I create the object

```
        consumption = Consumption.objects.create(
            client=client,
            rule=rule,
            course=course,
            provider=provider,
            usercode=data_from_request['CODIGO USUARIO'],
            username=data_from_request['NOMBRE USUARIO'],
            accessdate=access_date,
            billable=data_from_request['FACTURABLE'],
            status=data_from_request['VALIDADO']
        )
```

How is this possible? I'm debugging my code and when I check for the "access_date" variable content I can see the tzinfo filled

[image]

Why am I still getting this warning?
Thank you guys !

Comment: addedtime  received a naive not accessdate

Comment: Can you add `addedtime` in your question's model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you Consumption model probably look alike:

```
class Consumption(models.Model):
    ...
    accessdate = models.DateField("Fecha de acceso", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    ....
    addedtime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()) # this is not timezone aware
```

replace it with

```
class Consumption(models.Model):
    ...
    accessdate = models.DateField("Fecha de acceso", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    ....
    addedtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Read your error message carefully! It not speaking about **accessdate** but about attribute **addedtime** that probably has some bad default value!

Learn more in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Comment: Nope, this is the way I declare the attribute:

accessdate = models.DateField("Fecha de acceso", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False) I'll update the question, maybe this would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: But read what he says: it's about **addedtime**. *addedtime* != *accessdate*.

Comment: I'm edited my answer to reflect addedtime != accessdate problem more precisely. But the answer still holds. If it is not we need to see part of code where you set addedtime attribute of Consumption.

Comment: Guys you were so right! I was wrong. I thought the error was on accessdate, i'm sorry. Thank you so so so much.